# directory hung after aborted wget

Tags: linux, ftp, freeze, wget

I recently tried to download a ftp directory online into a local directory by using `wget -m ftp://docs`

After a few files downloaded, the process appeared to freeze and downloaded halted. I tried ctrl+z to stop the process, but it didn't do anything. So I just force quit the terminal window.

Now when I try to run `ls` in the directory where I was downloading the files, nothing is listed and the terminal freezes again (ctrl+z wont un-hang it).

How can I fix this?

Here is what I get if I `strace` the directory I'm trying to list

```
strace ls /data/chudlerk/080526/
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/data/chudlerk/080526/"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1063000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8ca000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=114688, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffe39879b00)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local64/lib/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local64/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local64/lib/tls", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local64/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local64/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe39879b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=142766, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 142766, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a7000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PY\300+=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=124640, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3d2bc00000, 2221912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d2bc00000
mprotect(0x3d2bc1d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d2be1c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x3d2be1c000
mmap(0x3d2be1e000, 1880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3d2be1e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240!@+=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47760, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a6000
mmap(0x3d2b400000, 2128816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d2b400000
mprotect(0x3d2b407000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d2b606000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x3d2b606000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\23\3001=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19016, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3d31c00000, 2111776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d31c00000
mprotect(0x3d31c04000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d31e03000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3d31e03000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\36\3008=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=33816, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3d38c00000, 2126416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d38c00000
mprotect(0x3d38c07000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d38e06000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x3d38e06000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356\1*=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1930416, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a5000
mmap(0x3d2a000000, 3750184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d2a000000
mprotect(0x3d2a18a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d2a38a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x3d2a38a000
mmap(0x3d2a390000, 14632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3d2a390000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\300*=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23088, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3d2ac00000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d2ac00000
mprotect(0x3d2ac02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d2ae02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3d2ae02000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000^\200*=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=146592, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3d2a800000, 2212848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d2a800000
mprotect(0x3d2a817000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d2aa17000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x3d2aa17000
mmap(0x3d2aa19000, 13296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3d2aa19000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local64/lib/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\23\3007=\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=21152, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a4000
mmap(0x3d37c00000, 2113888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3d37c00000
mprotect(0x3d37c04000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3d37e03000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3d37e03000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a3000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0cbb8a1000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f0cbb8a17a0) = 0
mprotect(0x3d2be1c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d2b606000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d38e06000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d2a38a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d2ae02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d29e1f000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d2aa17000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3d37e03000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f0cbb8a7000, 142766)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f0cbb8a1a70)         = 27750
set_robust_list(0x7f0cbb8a1a80, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7ffe3987a3fc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7ffe3987a3fc, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f0cbb8a17a0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x3d2a805cb0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3d2a80f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x3d2a805d40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x3d2a80f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
stat("/selinux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1063000
brk(0x1084000)                          = 0x1084000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99164480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99164480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0cb5a0e000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("/data/chudlerk/080526/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/data/chudlerk/080526/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
getdents(3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure appears corrupted. You should run an offline `fsck` on the partition to fix it.